# No handler registered for type error in ShinyApp DTedit table

Tags: r, shiny

Having

```
library(DTedit)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("listing")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){
  update.callback <- function(data, olddata, row){
    print("Update callback")
    return(data)
  }
  
  delete.callback <- function(data, row){
    print("Delete callback")
    return(data)
  }
  
  insert.callback <- function(data, row){
    print("Insert callback")
    return(data)
  }
  # Dummy data
  new_df <- data.frame(
   list(1:2, c("First", "Second"))
  )
  # Force addition of bad names to df
  names(new_df) <- c("ID", "VALUE WITH : SPACE AND ARBITARY CHARACTERS")
  dtedit_form <-DTedit::dtedit(
        input, 
        output, 
        name = "listing", 
        thedata = new_df,
        callback.delete = delete.callback,
        callback.insert = insert.callback,
        callback.update = update.callback
  )
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Causes error

```
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: No handler registered for type listing_edit_VALUE WITH : SPACE AND ARBITARY CHARACTERS
  [No stack trace available]
Error in (function (name, val, shinysession)  : 
  No handler registered for type listing_edit_VALUE WITH : SPACE AND ARBITARY CHARACTERS
```

When trying to edit anything inside the server.

Is the only solution to use `make.names` when generating columns from some source? The variable `new_df`'s columns are generated from a database call and these values return strings which sometimes contain spaces, dots and other "carbage" characters. Down the line having column names in callback functions to be equal of those received from the database would make implementation more elegant. There is also the consideration for the user to see matching values for the database insertions versus the generated names.

Comment: And if you load the package? (`library(DTedit)`)

Comment: Yes I had. I have clarified the given code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incredibly hacky, but here is a solution using [my fork of `DTedit`](https://github.com/DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit)

- yes, it uses `make.names` to create 'sane' column names
- At 'edit' time, the original crazy names are used, with the `edit.label.cols` argument
- At 'display' table time, a customization to the `datatable.call` function defines the `colnames` with the original crazy names

I am afraid that still leaves you to convert the 'sane' names to 'crazy' names at the time of modifying the original database in your callback functions.

p.s. note that the `delete.callback` is defined a little differently to your original example.

David

```r
library(DTedit)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        uiOutput("listing")
    )
)
server <- function(input, output){
    update.callback <- function(data, olddata, row){
        print("Update callback")
        return(data)
    }
    
    delete.callback <- function(data, row){
        print("Delete callback")
        return(data[-row, ])
    }
    
    insert.callback <- function(data, row){
        print("Insert callback")
        return(data)
    }
    # Dummy data
    new_df <- data.frame(
        list(1:2, c("First", "Second"))
    )
    # Force addition of bad names to df
    newnames <- c("ID", "VALUE WITH : SPACE AND ARBITARY CHARACTERS")
    names(new_df) <- make.names(newnames)
    dtedit_form <-DTedit::dtedit(
        input, 
        output, 
        name = "listing", 
        thedata = new_df,
        edit.cols = names(new_df),
        edit.label.cols = newnames,
        callback.delete = delete.callback,
        callback.insert = insert.callback,
        callback.update = update.callback,
        datatable.call = function(...) {DT::datatable(colnames = newnames, ...)}
    )
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I shall try this and accept later if it works. I am otherwise occupied at the moment. Seems ok.